# Get request with query string params to (restdb) API always response the same answer, even when params change

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, parameters

Here's my header:

```
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'x-apikey': 'some-api-key',
```

When I send a GET request with the query `/users?q={"firstname": {"$regex": "jo"}}` after refreshing the page with ctrl+f5, the response match the query. When after that first request, I try another query: `/users?q={"firstname": {"$regex": "nat"}}`, the request to the server is successful (200), but the body response is the same than for the first query. I have to manually press ctrl+F5 to make the answer match the query, and it works kind of randomly, I'm not able to understand any logic. Get resquests like `/users?skip=25&max=25` works perfectly, so must be link to the use of the query string params.

I try all the possibilities of 'Cache-Control, but nothing worked.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this was due to an aggressive cache on a particular service, should be working fine now.